# What does the exponentiated generator of scale transformation do when it acts on a function?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, group-theory, conformal-field-theory, scaling

We know that $d/dx$ is the generator of translation in the sense that $$e^{ad/dx}f(x)=f(x+a)\tag{1}$$ which can be easily be proved from the Taylor series of $f(x+a)$.

Studying the very basics of conformal group/transformations suggest that the generator of scale transformation, at least in 3D, is given by $x_i\partial_i$ (summed over $i$). Can we assume that the generator of scale transformation is given by $x\frac{d}{dx}$ in 1D? If so, can we in a similar way prove that, the action of $e^{\lambda x \frac{d}{dx}}$ on a function $f(x)$ gives $f(e^{\lambda} x)$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does $\exp\left( ax\frac{d}{dx} \right)$ do on $\psi(x)$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/613217/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hint: Rewrite the dilation operator $$x\frac{d}{dx}~=~\frac{d}{d\ln |x|}$$ as a translation operator, and use OP's Taylor formula/translation eq. (1) to deduce that
$$e^{\lambda x \frac{d}{dx}}f(x)~=~f(e^{\lambda}x).$$